# VS code locally committed changes missing and approved branch 'not found' in master repo

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, repo

I created a local branch off the repo master, committed changes and pushed the branch to our Azure repo. It was checked and approved, but I noticed some of the committed changes weren't applied to the master files and when I open the branch it's "not found". No one would have deleted it, so any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Can you check Pull Request details? you should see code changes there.

Comment: Hi @matt, is the answer below to check the commit history view in azure repo helps? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

You could check the commit history view in azure repo to shows the history of all the commits for a particular branch in a repository. By default, all results are shown in reverse chronological order. Here is the document [Commit history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commit-history?view=azure-devops) for reference.

[image]

Besides, you could also run `git log [<options>] [<revision-range>] [[--] <path>…​]` command to get change details in local to see is there any unexpected change has made.